# Is there some seller that sells Hard Drives with Gibibyte capacity?

Tags: hard-drive, specifications

I'm curious to know if there's actually any seller that has endorsed the IEEE specification of Mebibytes and Gibibytes in the manufacturing of Hard Drives, i.e. selling a 500GB (GigaBytes) as an actual 465,7GiB (GibiBytes) or producing effectively 500GiB or better 512GiB hard drives and the like.

For an explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte

Comment: Why would you want them to? Thier use of giga- to mean 10^9 follows the usual metric definition.

Comment: It' more correct in digital terms, you wouldn't measure a dress in liters or count "a dozen of waters", that's incorrect as is counting 1000000 bytes = 1 Megabyte while actually they are registered as 1048576 bytes = 1 "actual" Megabyte = 1 Mebibyte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, I have never heard of one, and could not find one searching using Google.

The reason you are not likely to find anyone changing to use a real gigabyte is that it would put them at a marketing disadvantage. Imagine trying to explain the concept to a non-technical person...a nightmare. Otherwise, your drive just looks like it holds less.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte

Comment: Well one option could be show the two capacities side by side and explain what's one and the other, otherwise your argument makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Lex Yes, you could try that, but why would anyone try to explain to the general public, many of whom, are nowhere near as intelligent as the average user here, that their drive really isn't smaller. You might get through to many people, but I suspect most, would just not care, and not really want to hear it. I have had many customers tell me just that when I tried to explain something to them. Why even remotely risk losing business?

Comment: So customers really tell you that they don't care about an explanation O_o' ? Well I recognize risking losing business is bad, maybe they will just wait for the mind of customers to change (eventually) before doing something like that.

Comment: Some, but not many in 17 years, but if the busier they, often the less they care..."Just make it work" is what they want, so they can get back to their work.